# String to lowercase and replace spaces with underscore

Tags: xstring, substitution, textcase

I am trying to convert a predefined string in a variable to its lowercase and replace the spaces to underscore. But it's not working. The new string after conversion is
like this:

> gameΩ_ofΩ_Ω_rollingΩ_Ω_Ω_dice

Desired output is:

> game_of_rolling_dice

Can any one help me out please?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{textcase}

\newcommand{\questionsection}{Game of  rolling   dice}
\newcommand{\questionsectionfiltered}{\StrSubstitute{\questionsection}{ }{\textunderscore}[\SUBtemp]\MakeLowercase{\SUBtemp}}

\begin{document}
    \questionsectionfiltered
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perfect candidate for a token cycle.  EDITED to add lowercasing, as requested.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\Characterdirective{\addcytoks[x]{\explowerchar{#1}}}
\Spacedirective{\addcytoks{\textunderscore\allowbreak}}
\def\explowerchar#1{%
  \ifcase\numexpr`#1-`A\relax
   a\or b\or c\or d\or e\or f\or g\or h\or i\or j\or k\or l\or m\or
   n\or o\or p\or q\or r\or s\or t\or u\or v\or w\or x\or y\or z\else
   #1\fi
}

\newcommand{\questionsection}{Game of  rolling   dice, plus this should
  allow line breaks as well.  Let us see if it does}
\newcommand{\questionsectionfiltered}{\expandafter\tokencyclexpress
  \questionsection\endtokencyclexpress}

\begin{document}
    \questionsectionfiltered
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this looks simple but it is not lowercasing the whole string

Comment: @t.abraham I failed to see that requirement, but I will edit my answer to provide that

Comment: @t.abraham I have added the lowercasing feature, as well.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `expl3` that's more robust than `xstring` (and more flexible).

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\filter}{m}
 {
  \tabraham_filter:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__tabraham_filter_text_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tabraham_filter:n
 {
  % set the tl variable to the lowercased version of the input
  \tl_set:Nx \l__tabraham_filter_text_tl { \text_lowercase:n { #1 } }
  % replace spaces with underscores
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__tabraham_filter_text_tl { ~ } { \_ }
  % deliver the result
  \tl_use:N \l__tabraham_filter_text_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\questionsection}{Game of  rolling   dice}

\begin{document}

\filter{\questionsection}

\filter{Game of  rolling   dice}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to define a filtered version of some token list, so when using it you don't have to repeat the whole process.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\filter}{m}
 {
  \tabraham_filter:nn { #1 } { \tl_use:N }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\newfilteredcommand}{mm}
 {
  \tl_if_exist:NF #1
   {
    You~don't~want~to~silently~redefine~something,~do~you?
   }
   {
    \tl_new:N #1
    \tabraham_filter:nn { #2 } { \tl_set_eq:NN #1 }
   }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__tabraham_filter_text_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tabraham_filter:nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l__tabraham_filter_text_tl { \text_lowercase:n { #1 } }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__tabraham_filter_text_tl { ~ } { \_ }
  #2 \l__tabraham_filter_text_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\questionsection}{Game of  rolling   dice}
\newfilteredcommand{\questionsectionfiltered}{\questionsection}

\begin{document}

\filter{\questionsection}

\filter{Game of  rolling   dice}

\questionsectionfiltered

\texttt{\meaning\questionsectionfiltered}

\end{document}
```

The last line is to show that `\questionsectionfiltered` is what's expected.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It provides a user macro called `\LowercaseUnderscore`, which passes its argument to a Lua function called `function lc_underscore`, which does most of the work with the help of the Lua built-in functions `string.lower` and `string.gsub`.

The argument of `\LowercaseUnderscore` needn't be a string. It could be a LaTeX macro; if it is, the macro gets expanded before it is passed to the Lua function for final processing.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment and '\luastring' macro
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
  function lc_underscore ( s )
    s = string.lower ( s )
    s = string.gsub ( s , "%s" , "\\textunderscore" )
    return ( s )
  end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
\newcommand\LowercaseUnderscore[1]{%
    \directlua{tex.sprint(lc_underscore(\luastring{#1}))}}

\newcommand{\questionsection}{Game of  Rolling   Dice}

\begin{document}
\LowercaseUnderscore{\questionsection}
\end{document}
```